# 종이로된 What does the sentence mean?

Tags: meaning

> 사전은 낱말의 뜻을 서술하는 것 내지는 도표와 함께 모아 놓은 것, 또는 어떤 낱말과 대응하는 다른 나라말의 낱말을 가나다 순서대로 배열한 것이다. 많은 사전들은 발음기호도 포함하고 있으며 응용, 역사, 어원, 그림, 사용법, 예문을 서술하고 있다. 예전에는 **종이로된** 문서 형식의 사전을 많이 사용했으나 지금은 인터넷을 많이 사용한다.

This sentence is from [here](https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%EC%82%AC%EC%A0%84). at the top of that page.

종이 means a paper in my dictionary.

But 로된 ?

It is probably 종 이로된 or so on... But Korean language is written by a cluster of words for  differenciating them. So it may be not right.

된 means hard or tight or solid....

I have no idea. please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is either a minor typo or a spacing issue; it should be "종이로 된".

That should help you parse the sentence better.

종이 you have correctly identified as "paper".

로 is the standard particle for the instrumental case.

된 perhaps you need to have another look at. This is a form of the verb 되다, which *can* mean "to be hard/solid", but *here* it is the more common "to become", "to (come to) be".

In English, there is an idiomatic translation for the "-로 되다" when used for *materials* in this way: "to be made (out) of".

Comment: At the latter of this sentence, the paper dictionary and the electric dictionary ( exactly on the internet) is compared each other . It is written that both of them are currently a lot used. I think you are right.thank you very much for your search.